# javascript use response from function in calling function

Tags: javascript, node.js, geocode

I've got a basic example of of the node-geocoder, but I can't get the response to bubble up into the calling function

```
    var address = userUpdates.address + " " + userUpdates.city + ", " + userUpdates.state + " " + userUpdates.zip;

   geocoder.geocode(address)
        .then(function(res) {
              console.log(res);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
             console.log(err);
       });
```

The console.log produces the correct JSON

```
[ 
  { 
    latitude: 35,
    longitude: -78.5,
    country: 'United States',
    city: 'Clayton',
    state: 'North Carolina',
    stateCode: 'NC',
    zipcode: '27520',
    streetName: 'Main St',
    streetNumber: '100',
    countryCode: 'US' 
   }
 ]
```

but I can't assign the res to anything  that will persist outside the geocoder.geocode function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried creating a global variable outside of the geocoder.geocode function to hold the value?

```
   var globalRes = null;
   geocoder.geocode(address)
        .then(function(res) {
              globalRes = res;
              console.log(res);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
             console.log(err);
       });
```

Comment: I did and the the variable is null when I call it outside the geocode function.

Comment: Hm... are you sure you're calling the globalRes variable after geocoder.geocode() has completed and not before it has finished?

Comment: I copied your code in directly and added a send console.log outside the function .then. It returns NULL

Comment: The geocode function is asynchronous, thus even if the globalRes is used after the geocode function, that doesn't mean that the geocode function has actually finished. Try using a setInterval() to check the value of globalRes and see if the value changes after a few seconds. Something like:
`var intervalId = 0;
function isDone() {
 if (globalRes) {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
  alert('We have it!')
 }
}
intervalId = setInterval(isDone, 1000);`

Comment: Thanks.  I think I've got it now.  Run the update/save inside the isDone function replacing the alert seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do something like this:-

```
var response = null;
geocoder.geocode(address)
    .then(function(res) {
          response = res;
          console.log(res);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of callbacks.

Here is a simplified code example that should get you started.

```
function myBigFunction() {
  // Here is part 1:
  console.log("I am part 1");

  // Now, call something async and wait for the callback
  myAsyncFunction(function (result) {
    console.log("I am part 2, with the results from myAyncFunction");
  });

  function myAsyncFunction(callback) {
    var returnValue = "This is returned";

    window.setTimeout(function () {
      // Call the callback and make myBigFunction pick back up.
      callback(returnValue);
    }, 250);

  }

}
myBigFunction();
```

So, in your example you'd want something like:

```
function doGeoCoder(callback) {
   geocoder.geocode(address)
        .then(function(res) {
              callback(res);
              console.log(res);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
             console.log(err);
       });
}

doGeoCoder(function(res) {
  console.log("I'm in the calling function's callback with");
  console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: How do I reference the res in console.log(res) outside the doGeoCoder function?  It contains a JSON object with latitude and longitude.  I'd like to add them to a user update and save to a database.